# D2L Valence API email address validation logic

Tags: desire2learn

I need to know the email validation logic in d2l to implement the same in another system which integrates with d2l. we are having issues as the email which is valid in our system is getting an error when creating the same user in d2l. It appears it does not like "." and "@" consecutively however the full regex for this validation will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email integration between Brightspace and your institutional services is, I believe, documented, but is also complex. Because this is a service configuration topic that's typically part of deployment of the service, and not actual *use* of the service day to day, the documentation is not publicly accessible at this time but may be available by request through your institution's account. I would recommend that you pursue this line of inquiry via your Brightspace account manager or approved support contact.

Comment: Thanks Victor  - will do so.